# How to take the derivative of double integral?

Tags: integration, derivatives

How I can calculate the following derivative for any $z_{0}$?
$$\frac{\partial (\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{b}f(x,y,z,t)dxdy)}{\partial z}$$
Note the integral do not have closed form solution

Comment: What are you assuming about $f$?  For example, is it continuous as a function of $x,y,z$?  What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: use the definition of derivative at a point

Comment: f is a continuous function of all variables. I tried to use the definition of derivative at a point, but no success yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apply the Leibniz Rule of Integration twice. You will find that the upper and lower bound are not functions of z. So, it's just:$$\int^a_0\int^b_0\frac{\partial f(x,y,z,t)}{\partial z}dxdy$$ and $f(x,y,z,t)$ need to be continuous when x and y is on the Integration region.